# Does the unnecessary repeated mention of the printf to make the source code easy to read slow down the program?

Tags: c

As in the source code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
    printf("\n\tQuadratic Equation Solver");
    printf("\n\nUse this program to solve a quadratic equation.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I could have written all the text I wanted to output in a single statement, but I wrote it in two statements to make reading the source code easier for me. Is this considered bad programming practice and does it increase the execution time of the program?

Comment: The time to call `printf` is negligible compared to the time to print the characters on the screen. So this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Not in any meaningful way.

Comment: Maybe, but who cares since it makes the code 100% more readable. After all, that's why we use a language like C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may increase the execution time of the program, as you're making multiple function calls, instead of just one. However, the difference will be negligible, especially because your terminal output (inside printf) is likely to be the bottleneck in the execution. It's also really of concern if you're printing a *lot* to the console. I think most would agree code readability is more important than extremely small optimizations such as combining the text.

Answer (score 1):

the answer for **Is this considered bad programming practice and does it increase the execution time of the program? **
is No and No